# awk print $0 with newline separated column values

Tags: bash, awk

**Input:**

`"prefix_foo,prefix_bar"`

**Expected Output:**

```
foo
bar
```

This is what I've so far.

```
$ echo "PREFIX_foo,PREFIX_bar" | awk '/PREFIX_/{x=gsub("PREFIX_", ""); print $0 }'
foo,bar
```

I'm unable to figure out how to print foo and bar separated by a newline. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

- **Length of input is unknown so there can be more than 2 words separated by comma.**
- **This question is more towards learning awk language, not alternative gnu utils.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying out `awk`

```
 echo "PREFIX_foo,PREFIX_bar" | awk -F, -v OFS="\n" '{gsub(/PREFIX_/,""); $1=$1}1'
```

Comment: Thanks! How is your command different from mine? `awk -F, -v OFS="\n" '{gsub(/PREFIX_/, ""); $1=$1 ; print $0}'` ? I don't fully under the syntax of your command. Help is appreciated.

Comment: I set the input field separator to a comma `,` so and set the output field separator to a newline  `"\n"` and removed the `PREFIX_` like what you did using gsub. `$1=$1` set all the field to a newline and the last `1` means print.

Answer (score 3):

You may not need `awk` for this. Here is pure bash solution:

```
s="prefix_foo,prefix_bar"
s="${s//prefix_/}"
s="${s//,/$'\n'}"
echo "$s"
```

```
foo
bar
```

Here is one liner `gnu sed` for the same:

```
sed 's/prefix_//g; s/,/\n/g' <<< "$s"
```

```
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT: 2nd solution*** Adding more generic solution here as per OP's comments, this will Look for every field and check if its having `prefix` then it will print that column's 2nd part(after `_` one).

```
echo "prefix_foo,etc,bla,prefix_bar" | 
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/prefix/){
      split($i,array,"_")
      val=(val?val OFS:"")array[2]
    }
  }
  if(val){
    print val
  }
  val=""
}'
```

To print output field values in new line try:

```
echo "prefix_foo,etc,bla,prefix_bar" | 
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/prefix/){
      split($i,array,"_")
      print array[2]
    }
  }
}
'
```

---

---

***1st solution:*** For simple case(specific to shown samples) could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[_,]' '/prefix_/{print $2,$4}'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
echo "prefix_foo,prefix_bar" | awk -F'[_,]' '/prefix_/{print $2,$4}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We've one more interesting answer which is a lot shorter. (by @Jetchisel)

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi, I thought that too but then for sample `prefix_foo,etc,bla,prefix_bar` where if you don't want things like `etc,bla` it will come too in output that's why I didn't choose that one. Honestly this will be more generic in case you want only those fields which have `prefix` in them and you want to print only those ones.